# NodeJs AJAX undefined values for submit buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm using Node.js as server-side with express and ejs with Twitter Bootstrap as front-end. The page has a modal with a form and 2 submit buttons. **I want to display different messages depending on what button was used to submit with ajax** (later I will add other handlings but for now I just want to display messages). My problem is that **I can't get the value of the submitted button**.

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>test</title>

    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCreateMdl">Click here</button>


        <div id="modalCreateMdl" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Form</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" id="formTest" action="test" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                        <button type="submit" name="sub" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit1">SUBMIT 1</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                        <button type="submit" name="sub" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit2">SUBMIT 2</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="msgTest" style="display:none"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="/js/ajax.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("/home/mainuser/test_node/"));

app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.sub);
    if(req.body.sub == "submit1") {
        obj = {test : "json1"};
        console.log("submit number 1");
    } else if(req.body.sub == "submit2") {
        obj = {test : "json2"};
        console.log("submit number 2");
    } else {
        obj = {test : "json_default"};
        console.log("default");
    }
    res.json(obj);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formTest').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method : $(this).attr('method'),
            url : $(this).attr('action'),
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            success : onSuccessLoad,
            error : onError
        });
        return false;
    });
});
// ready

function onSuccessLoad(json) {
    $('#msgTest').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#msgTest').html(json.test);
    $('#msgTest').fadeIn('slow');
}

function onError(returnation) {
    alert("problem");
}
```

When I click on SUBMIT 1 button, I get the following output in the terminal :

```
undefined
default
```

and json_default is displayed on the page.

when it should be this in the terminal :

```
submit1
submit number 1
```

and json1 on the page.

When I remove ajax.js the console output is fine but obviously the json is displayed in a new page which is not what I want.

Comment: shouldn't this: `res.json(obj)`, be this? `res.send(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: I don't think so. Even if it's not what I want, "json_default" is correctly displayed on the page in the #msgTest div, it means that the json was sent correctly.

Answer (score 0):

'$(this).serialize()' return 'string', not 'object'

Comment: And? What do I have to change here to get the value of the submitted button in node js instead of undefined?

Comment: var serializeStr = $(this).serialize();
  var serializeArray = serializeStr.split('&');
  var params = {};
  for(var i=0;i<serializeArray.length;i++){
    var value = serializeArray[i].split('=');
    params[value[0]] = value[1];
  }

Comment: This is a modification in the ajax.js file but my problem is in the test.js file. When I post, the console.log(req.body.sub); in test.js gives me undefined instead of "submit1" or "submit2".

Comment: The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as <input>, <textarea>, and <select>: $( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();

Comment: It has no effect on Button

Comment: I replaced my buttons with inputs and nothing changed. When I say that I get undefined value, it's on server side, in the console (Konsole) where I type "node test.js" to launch the server. I think that a first step to resolve my problem would be to be able to get the value of the inputs (type="submit") on server side with ajax.js not removed from my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCreateMdl">Click here</button>


    <div id="modalCreateMdl" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Form</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="formTest" action="test" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" name="sub" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" name="sub" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="msgTest" style="display:none"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <script>
     $('input[name="sub"]').on('click',function() {
         var serializeStr = $('#formTest').serialize();
         var serializeArray = serializeStr.split('&');
         var params = {};
         for(var i=0;i<serializeArray.length;i++){
            var value = serializeArray[i].split('=');
             params[value[0]] = value[1];
         }
         $.ajax({
             method : $('#formTest').attr('method'),
             url : $('#formTest').attr('action'),
             data : params,
             success : onSuccessLoad,
             error : onError
         });
         return false;
     });
     function onSuccessLoad(json) {
         $('#msgTest').fadeOut('slow');
         $('#msgTest').html(json.test);
         $('#msgTest').fadeIn('slow');
     }

     function onError(returnation) {
         alert("problem");
     }
```